# How do i get to my Project Root Folder

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

Im using Android studio for my android app in macbook air yosimito.I dont know how to get to my project's root folder.I also dont know how to run gradlew tasks, please help thanks.

Comment: 1) Why do you need to access your project's files programmatically?
2) Which gradle tasks do you need to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code -

```
    ContextWrapper cw =new ContextWrapper(mContext);
    File path = cw.getFilesDir();
```

use above code in your activity where you want to get root path.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, im a newbie, may i know where to use the code please?